# Custom Lint Rules: To handle light bulb button for custom lint

Tags: android

How to Handle the fix button for lint while writing custom lint rules because in the button it appears to give full explaination but it does not not provide the fix option whereas for native lint warnings or errors it gives fix option also.

So how to create or provide that fix option so that I can correct the error with the correction provided by me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Light button can also be called as fix button for lint correction in android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider making a plugin for your Custom lint check in IntelliJ Idea Community edition, downloaded from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/, and follow the tutorial at http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/index.html.

After then you will come to know that to handle light bulb for the fix of your custom Lint warning you have to extend the IntentionAction class particularly.

And then search for deploying the plugin in the tutorial and finally you will come to know to put the jar of the plugin thus created in the Android Studio/Contents/plugins folder.